# Can Photoshop guide lines' coordinates be programmatically retrieved from a psd file?

Tags: coordinates, photoshop

I am curious if guide line coordinates (x coordinates actually) can be retrieved from a psd file.
Basically, let's say, I want to read the file from any programming language environment or open it using something that will provide me with the guide coordinates.
For clarity, I am talking about these lines:

[image: Photoshop Guides]

Comment: What do you mean by 'from a psd file'? You want to open a file in your app and retrieve the guides data or you want to use Javascript inside Photoshop to retrieve it?

Comment: I want to use for example Java to do what I ask. Also updated the question, at little bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know about Java but you can do that easily with Javascript. This script will alert coordinates for all the guides of the active document in default Photoshop units:

```
var myGuides = [];
for (var i = 0; i < activeDocument.guides.length; i++) {
    myGuides.push(activeDocument.guides[i].coordinate);
}
alert(myGuides);
```

So you can use values from `myGuides` for whatever reasons you need.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks mate. People can refer to this page to get information about how scripting in PS is done - [Photoshop Scripting](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html)